# A Simple, 2d cross-platform graphics library for c or c++?

Tags: c, graphics, cross-platform

As in title, i need a 2d graphics library that is cross-platform, and provides simple functions, like in Basic; essentially, i only need to paint a pixel a certain color-I do not need hardware acceleration, or any kind of 3d support. I've found a couple ones, but they're not cross-platform.

Anyone knows a solution for me?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What about [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)?

Perhaps it's a bit too complex for your needs, but it's certainly cross-platform.

Comment: SDL is indeed more than Agasa needs, but it should be straightforward enough to use.

Comment: It worked with minimal effort. The fact that sdl-config exist and that debian had all the stuff preinstalled helped a lot. I agree it's overkill but it's simple enough for what i need. Thanks a lot for everything!

Answer (score 16):

Am I missing something to wonder why noone suggests [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org)? To use it for 2d would be very simple. The OP only wants to color a pixel. It doesn't get simpler than glBegin/glColor/glVertex/glEnd.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't guarantee identical pixel output across implementations.

Comment: @user82238 that is correct, but does such hardware accelerated API exist? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922526/opengl-deterministic-rendering-between-gpu-vendor | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919307/is-there-a-2d-graphics-api-with-both-pixel-perfect-drawing-and-2d-hardware-accel (e.g. allowing accelerated sprite rotation / scaling / blending / z-order ).

Comment: And if he's simply doing RGB pixels, without fancy lighting/etc., I fail to see an implementation that would give a radically different output, if any difference at all. But, heck, now thinking about it 7.5 years later, he could just "blit" to an in-memory "screen", and use OpenGL/etc. simply to throw the result onto the screen.

Answer (score 15):

- [Qt 5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/)
- [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/)
- [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/)
- and many many more ...

[In no particular order.] However, if you have any other requirements, let us know. BTW: I am not just posting results of a Google query here, I have used all of these (and SDL -- wrote my first few games in SDL :) and I'd say without a set of requirements, it's very difficult to choose among the ones listed.

Comment: why qt 4.2? the latest version of qt is also good i reckon :)

Comment: I had the doc links for 4.2 handy -- so mentioned it in the post.

Comment: Agreed, Qt (4.5) is also an excellent choice.

Answer (score 11):

**Heavy-weight:**

- GTK
- QT
- WxWidgets

**Lightweight:**

- FLTK
- Fox
- Tk
- Lua IUP
- Ultimate++
- dlib

**Drawing frameworks without GUI widgets:**

- SDL
- Cairo

Answer (score 6):

http://www.allegro.cc/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegro_library

Answer (score 4):

One neat engine I came across is [Angel-Engine](http://code.google.com/p/angel-engine/). Info from the project site:

- Cross-Platform functionality (Windows and Mac)
- Actors (game objects with color, shape, responses, attributes,
  etc.)
- Texturing with Transparency
- "Animations" (texture swapping at defined intervals)
- Rigid-Body Physics

  - A clever programmer can do soft-body physics with it
- Sound
- Text Rendering with multiple fonts
- Particle Systems
- Some basic AI (state machine and pathfinding)
- Config File Processing
- Logging
- Input from a mouse, keyboard, or Xbox 360 controller

  - Binding inputs from a config file
- Python Scripting

  - In-Game Console

Some users (including me) have succesfully (without any major problems) compiled it under linux.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [DISLIN](http://www.dislin.de). It's cross platform, has support for many languages, and has very intuitive naming of routines.

Also, just noticed that nobody mentioned [PLPLOT](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/), also cross platform, multi lingual ...

Comment: While DISLIN seems pretty cool, it is worth noting that it cost $180 pr developer for non-commercial use.

Comment: @dagw - you mean for commercial use. It is free for non commercial use.

Answer (score 1):

Picasso graphic library you can used:  cross platform

https://code.google.com/p/picasso-graphic/

Comment: Still updated I see: https://onecoolx.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

A cross platform 2D graphics library for .Net is [The Little Vector Library](http://littlevectorlibrary.blogspot.co.uk/) 
You could use it in conjunction with Unity 3D (recommended) or Xamarin, for example, to create 2D graphics on a variety of platforms.

Comment: This seems to be only for .NET ? The OP asked for C/C++ and cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was very helpful for me!