# Compiler can't find sstream?

Tags: c, include, bgi

I am trying to compile a program which includes the `graphics.h` header file for C. I have added the `graphics.h` and `winbgim.h` header files in the include folder and also `libbgi.a` to lib folder.

Just for testing, I made a simple hello world program and included the `graphics.h` header file.

But on compiling I got the following error:

> In file included from firstc.c:2:0:
>   c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/graphics.h:30:59:
>   fatal error: sstream: No such file or directory compilation
>   terminated.

I tried to search in other forums as well, where the same question had been asked, but could not get an answer.

Another question, I came across other graphic options for C and C++ like openGL and DirectX. Should I learn these instead of graphics.h?

Comment: `<graphics.h>` is operating system specific. You might consider [libsdl](http://libsdl.org/) or [gtk](http://gtk.org/) (or in C++ [Qt](http://qt-project/)...) since they all probably run on more operating systems.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Thanks! As a beginner, which one should I begin with, and also which one would be more beneficial in the long run?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it. My suggestion actually would be to install Linux (most distributions have `libsdl`,`gtk`,`Qt` already) on your machine. Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`)

Comment: The interesting thing about Linux is that it is mostly (or fully, if you are careful) made of [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) whose source code you can study and improve. You'll learn a lot.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Thanks a lot! Yeah, as a computer science student I have got to learn all those things you mentioned. I already have Ubuntu along with Windows. I'll try my best :)

Comment: Take the habit of studying the source code of some free software you are using (perhaps start with your shell, or `/bin/ls`) ; you'll learn a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can get and use the header file <graphics.h> in my C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-i-can-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`graphics.h` is a non-standard header. Most likely it refers to the old BGI graphics library of the Turbo C DOS compiler. It will only work on that particular compiler. And of course DOS is a completely obsolete OS nowadays.

If you are interested in 3D graphics programming, then OpenGL and/or DirectX are indeed better, modern alternatives, supported by many compilers.

Comment: Notice that DirectX is Windows specific.

Comment: Thanks! So I can't use graphics.h (I have a gcc compiler). I tried searching for how to use OpenGL / DirectX, but there were two different types of solutions - either use them directly (using some <gl/glu.h>) header files or download glut/ freeglut / flgw etc. and use those header files (like <glut.h>). Which one would be easier, considering I don't know the basics of any graphic programming, and wish to use them only for my C/C++ programs?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Yes, which has now left me wondering if I should use it or OpenGL. Is it true that programs made using OpenGL are not much effective on a Windows Platform? I have both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: The main issues with OpenGL on Windows is that by default Windows only comes with a software-only OpenGL 1.x API. To have hardware support or any newer version of OpenGL requires installing a 3rd-party ICD driver. That said, many driver packages from AMD/ATI, NVidia, and Intel come with these ICDs.

Answer (score 5):

If you try to compile the source code with including “graphics.h” in code::blocks IDE you have to setup `winBGIm` library.

- Download `WinBGIm` from http://winbgim.codecutter.org/ or use ([direct link](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/V6_0/WinBGIm_Library6_0_Nov2005.zip))
- Extract it.
- Open `graphics.h`, go to line **`302`** change `int right=0` to `int top=0`
- Copy `graphics.h` and `winbgim.h` files in include folder of your compiler directory.
- Copy `libbgi.a` to lib folder of your compiler directory
- In code::blocks open `Settings` >> `Compiler and debugger` >> `linker settings`
- Click `Add` button  in link libraries part, browse and select `libbgi.a` file
- In right part (ie. other linker options) paste commands
  `-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32`
- Click `Ok`

You can also check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWmis4uVCHg) tutorial.

[image: Compiler options]

Comment: Thanks! What does changing `int right=0` to `int top=0` do?

Answer (score 2):

When you're compiling a C source code having graphics.h header file, you'll need to change the file extension to .cpp. Without doing that, you'll get “fatal error: sstream : no such file directory” error.

So, simply change the .c extension to .cpp. Here's a [step-by-step procedure](http://www.codewithc.com/how-to-include-graphics-h-in-codeblocks/) to compiling graphics.h source code if you're using Code::Blocks to run the code.

Comment: But still I am unable to run simple programs. When I execute, it says "program stops working".

Answer (score 1):

The sstream error occurs only when you are compiling using gcc not g++ , try using g++ or converting the program to c++ , as far as i know ( since i'm new to this language but i've faced this error before ) so goodluck with that

Answer (score 0):

If top answer doesn't work, and you are getting:

- `error: narrowing conversion of 'x' from 'int' to 'short unsigned int'`
- your graphics window just doesn't appear

  following [this](https://tejassproxy.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-setup-winbgim-library-in.html) tutorial and using the bug fixed headers/libraries (`winBGIm(bug-free).rar`) in the provided winBGIm source link, worked for me in Windows 10.

[Mirror](https://bitbucket.org/sasafras12/winbgim/src/master/) to `winBGIm(bug-free_.rar)`

compiling with: `g++ example.cpp -Wall -m32 -std=c++11 -pedantic -g -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32 -o example.exe`

Answer (score -1):

this process is abosulitly right.
doing this process step by step your code is compile and execute.
change the extension of your program to .c to .cpp
step1. https://youtu.be/CHFyEnlMnxg
through this video follow all step.