# Codeblocks graphics.h not working

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

When I do:

```
#include <graphics.h>
```

It says:

> fatal error: graphics.h: No such file or directory

How to fix this?

I'm using codeblocks 16.01

Comment: `graphics.h` isn't a c++ standard header. What toolchain are you using? IIRC the only one supporting that out of the box is the ancient Turbo C++ compiler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313534/how-to-use-graphics-h-in-codeblocks/46300800

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error due to #include<graphics.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839752/error-due-to-includegraphics-h)

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Download graphics.h library from http://winbgim.codecutter.org/ or use this [link](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/).

Step 2: Extract the downloaded file. You’ll get three files:

```
graphics.h
winbgim.h
libbgi.a
```

Step 3: Copy and paste graphics.h and winbgim.h files into the include folder of your compiler directory. (If you have Code::Blocks installed in C drive of your computer, go through: `Disk C >> Program Files >> CodeBlocks >> MinGW >> include`. Paste these two files there.)

Step 4: Copy and paste libbgi.a to the lib folder of your compiler directory.

Step 5: Open Code::Blocks. Go to `Settings >> Compiler >> Linker settings`

Step 6: In that window, click the Add button under the “Link libraries” part, and browse and select the libbgi.a file copied to the lib folder in step 4.

Step 7: Go to “Other linker options” on the right part and paste these commands:

```
-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32
```

Step 8: Make sure you got steps 6 and 7 right! Here’s a screenshot of previous two steps. Then, click Ok.

```
Graphics.h in codeblocks - Compiler Settings
Global Compiler Settings >> Linker Settings
```

Step 9: If you now try compiling a graphics.h program code in C or C++, you’ll still get error. To solve it, open graphics.h file (pasted in include folder in step 3) with text editor. Go to line number 302, and replace that line with this line:

```
"int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX"
```

if it is correct(same as above) then leave it as it is

Save the file. Done!

Now you can compile any C or C++ program containing `graphics.`h header file. If you compile C codes, you’ll still get an error saying: `“fatal error: sstream : no such file directory”`. For this issue, if your file extension is `.`c, change it to `.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the angle brackets "<>" assumes graphics.h is part of the C standard library. After some research, it appears this file is no longer included in the library. If you wish to continue using this library, you will have to find graphics.h and place it in the same location as your source code.

In your source code, you will then write: 
`#include "graphics.h"`

Comment: `graphics.h` was never in the Standard C Library.

Answer (score 2):

paste the graphics.h and winbgim.h into C:\MinGW\include folder. Then paste libbgi.a to C:\MinGW\lib. this solution will be worked. because your default compile's installation location set to C:\MinGW. otherwise you can change your compile's installation location in codebolck. 
Setting>> Global Compiler setting>> Toolchain executable

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution from here(You can refer this for more details): [How to use graphics.h in code blocks?](https://erainnovator.com/how-to-include-graphics-h-in-codeblocks/)

**Step 1:** To setup “graphics.h” in CodeBlocks, first set up winBGIm graphics library. [Download WinBGIm from Borland BGI emulation for MingW](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/).

**Step 2:** Extract the downloaded file. There will be three files:

```
1. graphics.h
2. winbgim.h
3. libbgi.a
```

**Step 3:** Copy and paste graphics.h and winbgim.h files into the include folder of compiler directory. (If you have Code::Blocks installed in C drive of your computer, go through: Disk

> C >> Program Files >> CodeBlocks >> MinGW >> include

. Paste these two files there.)

**Step 4:** Copy and paste libbgi.a to the lib folder of compiler directory.

**Step 5:** Open Code::Blocks. Go to

> Settings >> Compiler >> Linker settings

.

**Step 6:** In that window, click the Add button under the “*Link libraries*” part, and browse.

Select the libbgi.a file copied to the lib folder in step 4.

**Step 7:** In right part (ie. other linker options) paste commands

```
-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32
```

**Step 8:** Click Ok

**Step 9:** Try compiling a graphics.h program in C or C++, still there will be an error. To solve it, open graphics.h file (pasted in include folder in step 3) with Notepad++. Go to line number 302, and replace that line with this line : `int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,`

**Step 10:** Save the file. Done!

*Note :*

Now, you can compile any C or C++ program containing graphics.h header file. If you compile C codes, you’ll still get an error saying: “fatal error: sstream : no such file directory”.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still getting error (linker error) after following the above solutions.
The build of the library at   http://winbgim.codecutter.org/ is old and was last built around 2006.While linking against that using 64 bit toolchain results into linking error. [Here](https://github.com/ki9gpin/WinBGIm-64) is a recent build of the library bringing 64 bit compatibility. 
Some win32 system call has also been updated to recommended 64 bit alternates to make it  work.