# How to add C graphics.h library in Eclipse IDE

Tags: c, eclipse, bgi, winbgi

I'm trying to use some C graphic functions in Eclipse. I've copied  WinBGIm files in the include/lib directories inside MINGW, but graphics.h library doesn't work yet.what is the solution?

c:\mingw\include\graphics.h:30:10: fatal error: sstream: No such file or directory

Comment: I think the library and header file only works with C++.

Comment: Graphics libraries are available for c. You can check the version of your mingw compiler.

Comment: some what related answer here...[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839752/error-due-to-includegraphics-h]