# ld.exe -lgraph not found

Tags: c++, bgi

i keep getting this error when i try to run a simple graphics code.
and i dont think the problem is with the code itself.

```
Desktop\CG> g++ -w bres-circle.cpp -o bres-circle -lgraph
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgraph
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm,"");

    line(100,100,200,200);
    closegraph();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error due to #include<graphics.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839752/error-due-to-includegraphics-h)

Comment: `-lgraph` means "link in libgraph.a or libgraph.so". Do you have either of those files, and are they in a place that g++ can find them? (It might also accept libgraph.lib for Windows-targeted compilers.) If you need to specify an extra library path then that's `-L <path>`, and put that before the `-lgraph`.

Comment: (There may also be command line parameter order issues - the order for linking is significant. Maybe try putting the -lgraph before the -o too? But I don't think that's a problem.)