# Can graphics.h header work on 64bit windows?

Tags: c++, c, bgi

I installed graphics.h library on Dev-C++ but it wont run my code as it gives me this error in the compiler:

> **int left=0,
>
>   int right=0,
>
>   int right=INT_MAX,
>
>   int bottom=INT_MAX,**

*Here's my code:*

```
#include <graphics.h>
void main( )
{

 initwindow(800, 800, "line");
 line(200,200,200,600);
 getch();
}
```

They told me `graphics.h` can't work on 64-bit windows... Is that right?...

Comment: What's `graphics.h`?

Comment: `graphics.h` is not standard C header. Where did you get it?

Comment: Have you googled this?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Apparently it's a [graphics library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-i-can-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program) old enough to be considered "antique".

Comment: _"it give me this error in the compiler"_ I don't see the error? Please paste the full error.

Comment: What is the error? Who is "they"? Why are you using antiques? Assuming you mean the graphics.h from Turbo C++, that is literally from the 1980s.

Comment: when i compile it opens a new tab named graphics.h and it highlight this text:     int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,

Comment: my teacher told me it can't work on 64 bit windows,also sorry for my bad english

Comment: Listen to your teacher. graphics.h is an old MS DOS VGA graphics library for the Turbo C compiler. Unless you plan to become a maintainer of old DOS junk, I would suggest that you pick up some more modern graphics lib.

Comment: ok fine, the graphics.h is a subject in my univercity is there any similar library i can study on it that run on 64bit win?

Comment: @EzzeddineSaaid [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/)

Comment: You should ask your teacher how to configure your compiler to build for 32-bit Windows environment.

Comment: thanks for help everyone :)

Comment: If you don't visit this university for it's history classes, I'd suggest also getting a good, recent book on C or C++ to study what you will need for the job. Turbo C++ is what the donkey cart is to modern engineering. It was good at the time, but we don't live in those times any more. Even the combustion engine is on it's way out, don't learn how to drive a donkey cart.

Comment: Consider using C++11 (with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler) and [Qt](http://qt.io/)

Comment: Consider replacing `,` with `;` for your declarations.  Another idea is to remove `int` for additional variables (e.g. `int a, b, c;`).

Answer (score 2):

[WinBGIm](http://winbgim.codecutter.org/) is a 32-bit library only. There were no 64-bit version of  Windows (except for the Itanium) when it was written.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone download this from the official site, open the graphics.h in any text editor, and exactly at line 303:

```
int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX
```

change the second `right` to `top` (redeclaration error).

This library will only run on x32 bit compilers. So if you're running something ancient like Bloodshed DevC, Turbo C, or CodeBlocks, then you're fine. But if you're using Visual Studio and your assigments force you to use that library, then good luck making that happen.