# Application using the winbgi library crashes when used with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, bgi, winbgi

I am having trouble when trying to run a graphics program through codeblocks. It just opens console and crashes when I click the build&run button. I have tried many other graphics program the result is still the same. And also I tried to debug it and it says segmentation error. See the picture for more details.

[image: picture of the problem]

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {
    int gdriver = DETECT, gmode;
    int x1 = 200, y1 = 200;
    int x2 = 300, y2 = 300;
    char driver[] = "";

    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, driver);
    line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm, Probabaly not. Probably just a weird way of doing `const char *driver = "";`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-i-can-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can get and use the header file <graphics.h> in my C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-i-can-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program)

Comment: The error is confusing, it is about `std::string` which I don't think the `winbgi` port uses. Could be that your compiler is too new. Remember that the binaries for `winbgi` are now 14 years old. You likely need an old compiler to match. Something from 2005 to 2007 not 2019.

Comment: Please make your title describe the question