# How can I use graphics.h header in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, bgi

I was working on a graph question on my vs code. I used the graphics.h header but it is not working. I tried it on online editors too but the same problem is arriving there.

How can I use this header?

Comment: What is `graphics.h`?  This is not a standard header.

Comment: If you are referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67450208/how-to-add-chess-pieces-in-graphics-h#comment119219645_67450208), please read the comments.  The reason why `graphics.h` is not working is simple -- it is old, outdated, and not used in todays computer world.  A modern C++ compiler and build system will not waste resources on maintaining such an old system.

Comment: Throw a rock and you [hit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-i-can-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program).

Comment: "graphics.h" is for Borland BGI.  Which is an obsolete graphics library for an obsolete OS (DOS) and targets an obsolete version of C++.  There are plenty of up-to-date graphics libraries to choose from: pick one of those.  See also: [How can I get and use the header file <graphics.h> in my C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-can-i-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program)

Comment: If you are looking for a version of BGI which will work with Visual Studio: https://github.com/nirin/WinBGI