# What to use when drawing shapes in C?

Tags: c, bgi

I've been having some problems trying to figure out with header is useful to manage to get a screen, and draw shapes in it, using C.

Tried to use 'graphics.h' but is not working for me, I think maybe 'graphics.h' is meant to be used in C++ and not C? I really don't know and would appreciate it if someone knows anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get and use the header file <graphics.h> in my C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860569/how-can-i-get-and-use-the-header-file-graphics-h-in-my-c-program)

Comment: There is no standard library for graphics in C.  This depends on your operating system, amongst other factors.  Some common and reasonably well-supported libraries across multiple platforms are OpenGL and Qt.  Beyond this, specify your target operating system.  `graphics.h` sounds like an ancient Windows or DOS library.

Comment: Ahh, yes...  TurboC.  That's where I remember it from!  Hahah thanks for the link, kaylum.

Comment: I'm trying to get display of graphics in C language, having everything installed in WSL (Ubuntu dist)

Comment: I checked the link sent by kaylum. Tried with the SDL option and didn´t got it to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you can't build a graphical app using only stdlib. You have to add something like OpenGL, Xlib, maybe Qt or even SFML. Good luck to make an app)

Answer (score 1):

I believe `graphics.h` is a Windows-specific library. Assuming you're on Linux, you can use [gfx](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Edthain/courses/cse20211/fall2013/gfx/).

`gfx` is an xlib-based graphics library with some very basic functions to draw lines/pixels and get keyboard input. I wouldn't use it in a serious project, but it's fairly easy to get started with. You can even add functionality to draw more complex shapes if you mess with the source code and some XLib functions.

If that's too basic, you can use [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/) for 2D graphics, OpenGL for 3D graphics, and [ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) for terminal-based graphics.

Comment: I would rather say that combination SDL + OpenGL is good and portable for both 2D and 3D graphics